# UIAlertController backgroundColor washed out

Tags: ios, swift2, uicolor, uialertcontroller

trying to set a `UIAlertController` `backgroundColor` but the result is a "washed out" color

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "some title", message: "(tap to continue)", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:{

                let subview = alert.view.subviews.first! as UIView
                let alertContentView = subview.subviews.first! as UIView
                alertContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

By "washed out" I mean it's not bright yellow but more like a faded yellow color...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ideas?  Well, somewhere in Apple's internal hierarchy of layers and views, something is semi-transparent.  You might track down what it is, but you are treading dangerous ground here.  The Apple docs explicitly state

> You cannot customize the appearance of alert views.

so even if you solve this, it might not work on all iOS versions or all devices.  If you need to customize the appearance don't use Alert Views; create your own Modal View instead.

Comment: Do you mean that the above code will be rejected by Apple?

Comment: Not rejected; just not the right approach for guaranteeing consistency among all the devices and os versions the code might wind up running on.